# Reading static resources in Springboot for custom swagger-ui

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc

`I'm using springdoc-openapi.  I want to customize the swagger, so I copied the whole thing to my resources directory

[image]

I am also not loading the files from the jar

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

But I can't seem to serve any files inside swagger-ui.  I tried moving it to `static/swagger-ui`, but I still get a 404.

When the service starts up, it shows

```
Patterns [/webjars/**, /**, /swagger-ui*/**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
```

So it looks like openapi is adding those resource paths.

But both `http://localhost/index.html` and `http://localhost/swagger-ui/index.html` return 404

I *am* able to go to `http://localhost/hello.html`, which is in `resources/static`, one of the default locations for static files.  Why can't I read the `index.html` file that's in the `swagger-ui` directory, either in `resources/swagger-ui` or `resources/static/swagger-ui`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this,  you need to extend the implementation of SwaggerIndexPageTransformer. Next, add transformer @Bean to your @Configuration.

> Please follow the instruction provided in the doc-
> https://springdoc.org/v1/#customizing-swagger-static-resources

**Note:-** Spring doc v1 is only compatible with Spring-boot v2.